# No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.deterministic' in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, statsmodels

During a Kaggle course (Time Series), I had to use statsmodels in google colab but I faced this Error

> No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.deterministic'

because of:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.deterministic import DeterministicProcess
```

I've searched for my issue but most of the answers were about the version of SciPy and statsmodels. I tried all of them, but none worked. Maybe it is because of out of date answers (all of them were for 2019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this issue before and according to the documents it can be installed using:

```
!pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels
```

After installation, a restart run time is required.